# Creating a way to handle textbox validation

Tags: vb.net

I have a time entry form that contains a tabcontrol with tab pages for each day of the week.  Within this control is a table layout panel that is holding together various textboxes/labels.  For each day of the week, the inputs are named in a similar fashion:

```
txtMonWorkHours
txtMonPTOHours
txtMonOTHours
txtTuesWorkHours
txtTuesPTOHours
txtTuesOTHours
...
```

I am using ADO.net to load/save all these values from a database into their respective textboxes.

[image: Photo of data entry form]

What I am now trying to do now is provide a method to validate entry (which I have now finished on an individual event basis such as:

```
Private Sub txtMonIn_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMonIn.Leave
    ValidateTimeEntered(txtMonIn)
   End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub txtMonIn_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtMonIn.TextChanged
    TransitionTextPreValidate(txtMonIn)
End Sub
```

My question is: Is there a way to add the method I have created to all the textboxes I need without having to assign each method to each textbox event individually?

Comment: you can edit the Handles portion of the declaration `...Handles txtMonIn.TextChanged, txtTueIn.TextChanged .....` so all the TxtIn??? use the same proc, ditto with the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your events have the ability to **handle** multiple controls, that is why the "sender" object is passed, so you know who is calling the event.  Try this, **notice the end of the sub's declaration**:

```
Private Sub txtWeekdayIn_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles  txtMonIn.Leave, txtTueIn.Leave, txtWedIn.Leave
    ValidateTimeEntered(sender)
End Sub
```